# I'm getting this message when restarting Apache after installing litespeed on my dedicated server:

Tags: apache, whm, litespeed

I'm getting this error when trying to restart Apache after installing litespeed on my dedicated server:

```
    Apache restarted, but pid file does not match process list pids.

If apache restart reported success but it failed soon after, 
it may be caused by   oddities with mod_ssl.

You should run /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/ssl_crt_status as part of your 
troubleshooting process. Pass it --help for more details.

Also be sure to examine apache's various log files.
Apache Restart Output:

Log:
2013-02-09 20:54:17.062 [NOTICE] [Child: 15131] Shut down successfully! 
2013-02-09 20:54:17.066 [NOTICE] [AutoRestarter] cleanup children  
processes and unix sockets of process with pid=15132 !
2013-02-09 20:54:17.070 [NOTICE] [AutoRestarter] child process with 
pid=15132 exited with status=0!
2013-02-09 20:54:17.070 [NOTICE] [AutoRestarter] cleanup children processes 
and unix sockets of process with pid=15131 !
2013-02-09 20:54:17.170 [NOTICE] [AutoRestarter] child process with 
pid=15131 exited with status=0!
2013-02-09 20:54:17.170 [NOTICE] [PID:15129] Server Stopped!
2013-02-09 20:54:18.200 [NOTICE] [AutoUpdate] Checking for new releases..., pid=15272
2013-02-09 20:54:18.201 [NOTICE] Start to clean up cache directory, pid=15273
2013-02-09 20:54:18.518 [INFO] [AutoUpdate] No new update.
[Sat Feb 09 20:54:19 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled  
(wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Sat Feb 09 20:54:19 2013] [notice] Apache/2.0.64 (Unix) 
mod_ssl/2.0.64 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 
mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I don't have enough experience to workout what the issue is , but I'm trying to learn... any help would be appreciated..thanks

Specs:

- CENTOS 6.3 x86_64
- WHM 11.34
- PHP Version 5.3.21
- Litespeed 4.2.1
- Server Version:Apache/2.0.64 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.64 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips
  mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
- LiteSpeed is running (PID = 15263). Apache is running (PID = 15335).
- suEXE enabled

Comment: Wouldn't this be better fit for [ServerFault?](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: quit right, will move it thanks...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am currently experiencing it and I can not find a repost of this question on ServerFault.